# Can recursive acronyms for projects consist trademark brands?

Tags: intellectual-property, software, trademark, business

Example of known [recursive acronyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_acronym):

- GNU - GNU's Not Unix
- Wine - Wine Is Not an Emulator

Can you use similar approach by including into your project name the letters from major registered trademark brands?

For example:

- TNI - TNI's Not I.B.M.
- FINW OS - FINW Is Not Windows

Especially when it clearly states your project is not about them.

And to be clear, the project is going to be always advertised by using the acronyms only.
And the meaning of acronym is going to be only expanded in some project brief docs (more like a fun fact).

Comment: Similar: [Can your business have the same initials as a major corporation?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/39114/529)

Comment: Note: Linux is not an acronym. And neither of the two hypothetical examples for recursive acronyms you give are recursive.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Check the definition of [recursive acronym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_acronym) (example: _TINT Is Not TECO_). And [What does LINUX stand for?](https://www.acronymfinder.com/Linux-Is-Not-Unix-(LINUX).html).

Comment: A recursive acronym is an acronym where the acronym itself occurs as part of the expansion of the acronym. Neither of your two examples have that property, therefore, they are not recursive acronyms. And your second source is simply wrong. Linux does not stand for anything. Linus Torvalds did *not* want to name it after himself, because he thought that would be arrogant, so he named it *Freax*, and he sent it to a friend and asked him to upload it to the university's fileserver. However, the friend thought that *Linux* sounded cooler, so he renamed the file. Neither Freax nor Linux stand for …

Comment: … anything, they are just neologisms based on the common trope of ending words related to Unix with *X*, e.g. Minix (a small Unix-like OS with a microkernel).

Comment: I've updated examples to include the acronym itself.

Comment: Does not your new example answer your question, as [UNIX is a registered trademark of The Open Group](https://unix.org/trademark.html)